# Organizer in Xcode 6.3.2 - No estimate binary size

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

In the previous versions of Xcode there was a place to estimate your archive/binary file size of your app. From organizer after you archive you can simply click estimate file size. In 6.3, there is no such button or function! Oddly enough in Xcode 6.2 betas this feature is still there. Is it located somewhere hidden or am I missing something? Please advise if they deprecated this functionality. You can view the file or archive in the finder but it's not the same as "estimate size".

This is imperative if you want to create your app below the 150mb threshold. It was helpful to keep my app under the 150mb cellular download limitation for increased "impulse" buys from iOS users. It's much easier in Android OS, since you can simply view the size of your APK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IPA/App size does not give you a reliable final size estimate for the App Store. Apple re-encrypt the executable which generally means it will not compress as well as that which is in the package you upload for submission.

Once you have the .app(*) you need to do a “Show Package Contents” on it, find the executable and move it out of the .app. Compress the .app as a .zip (making sure the executable is no longer contained within it) and make a note of that size. Add that number to the size of the uncompressed size of the executable, add on ~100K and that will give you an absolute maximum final package size:

```
TheorecticalMax = CompressedAppWithoutExec + UncompressedExec + 100K
```

In reality you will still get a decent compression ratio on you executable (if you know the AppStore size of a previous release, or Apple have informed you of it post-submit, you can work out the compression ratio for your last submit). As an example, we got about an 82% compression ratio on a 32bit+64bit executable built in Unity 5.0.1 for a 2D match-three title, so in our case this is how out numbers worked out:

> Submitted IPA size: 78.2MB
>
> Apple reported size after AppStore preparation: 107.4MB (!)

After some serious optimizations, we got our .ipa down to:

```
IPA: 62MB
Uncompressed executable: 76.6MB (!!! THANKS UNITY !!!)
Compressed executable assuming similar 82% compression: 62.8MB
APP minus executable: 85.8MB
Compressed APP minus executable: 33.7MB
```

Which gives us a final estimate of:

```
76.6*0.82 + 33.7 + 0.1 = 96.6MB
```

Still cutting it close, but we submitted a few days ago and have yet to receive anything from Apple saying we’re over 100MB (they previously reported a few hours after submission the last time, must be an automated check)

(*) To get the .app from a .xcarchive, simply “Show Package Contents”, then `“Products->Applications”`. From a .ipa, rename it to .zip, uncompress as any .zip file, then look in “Payload"

Comment: Apple encrypts the executable code, not the resources.. Encrypted data is not compressible, there are no patterns, it is essentially random bytes.

Comment: Here's also a nice guide: http://www.indiepinion.com/steffenj/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-iphone-app-after-approval/

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: @d4Rk - that's a great link, I'll send that to peeps in future!

Comment: @zaph - yes, the encryption of executables hides patterns, but you can still get some, it doesn't necessarily mean it's un-compressable. This is why people see the AppStore size sometimes being quite different (larger) than what they submitted. With executables the size that Unity is spitting out, there's bound to still be some patterns after encryption, just not a lot for a compression algorithm to work with.

Comment: @chadsmash Incorrect, encrypted data is indistinguishable from random data. Random data has no patterns. I took an app executable, encrypted it AES 128-bit, CBC with PKCS#7 padding and zip'ed it. Here are the results (clear means un-encrypted): clearAppData size: 7,338,096 bytes cryptAppData size: 7,338,112 bytes (encryption make the file larger by one block for the padding) clearAppFile zip size: 2,138,238 bytes cryptAppFile zip size: 7,340,510 bytes. Zipping made the encrypted file 2,398 bytes larger than the zip'ed un-encrypted file. If you want the code I can supply it.

Comment: i made an ipa for adhoc which has 25mb, another for appstore which is 43mb. if i look on my ipad the game has 112,5mb. is the after install size of 112mb relevant for the 100mb limit? or only the ipa size for the appstore?

Comment: Yes, installed size doesn't matter - as long as the size of the package to download on the AppStore is under 100MB then it can be downloaded over cellular. Although you do want to keep your unpacked/install size down as much as possible, as you don't want to be the app that gets deleted to free up space :-) 112MB is not bad though

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally found a hokey way to get an estimated size. You view the archive in the finder once finished, then you open package contents. Under your xcarchive file. There is a Products/Applications directory. Open your xcarchive in finder, then show package contents.

Browse to -> Products -> Applications -> (name of product) and you can view file size. The file size is about 5mb bigger than what the estimate product is (I'm not sure about this reason).

Comment: What do you mean with browse to Products? Package content usual don't contain a Product folder.

Comment: under your xcarchive file. There is a Products/Applications directory.

Comment: Open your xcarchive in finder, then show package contents. You will see the directory.

Comment: @peko sorry but you are mistaken. My product archives all have this folder. Clearly.

Comment: Intriguing approach and very easy. Does anyone know how well this correlates to Apple's actual calculated size?

Comment: There's a discrepancy of a few megs +/-

Answer (score 1):

You could create an App thinning report by following Apple docs below,

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Plus there are some optimzation tips.

Answer (score 0):

In the organizer you need to export an archive like "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment". You can use "Use local signing assets". It will export an IPA file. Size of this file is estimated size of the archive on App Store.

Comment: Are you saying that this encrypts the executable and then compresses the ipa? If so have you verified that? Tested that and found the executable to be uncompressed. So this method does not work. If you disagree please supply a rebuttal.

Comment: It works well for me. IPA is a encrypted and compressed file. Option "estimate size" in previous versions of Xcode used to show a archive size, not binary size. Binary size you can explorer without packing to an IPA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best estimate of the Apple store size, uncompress the app's IPA file, replace the executable with an exact same size file of random bits (thus making it incompressible), then zip the resulting (unexecutable) IPA folder and check the resulting zip file size.

Comment: Also wondering why the down vote instead of a comment. Best guess is that there a substantial number of developers on SO who believe that encrypted data is compressible or don't understand that encrypted data indistinguishable from random data.